# How to make a very simple RPM for RedHat

Tags: redhat, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to make a very simple RPM installation file for RedHat.

This file must only put my binary to `/usr/bin` and my configuration file to `/usr/etc.`

I don't want to put my sources on the *RPM*.

Comment: There are any number of (varying quality) guides to building an rpm package online (not least of which is http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-basics.html which is linked from the [rpm-spec] tag wiki). Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck specifically? What version of RedHat/Fedora/CentOS are you building this on and what version(s) are you building this rpm for?

Comment: Since packages in Red Hat distribution mostly follows fedora package guidelines, you can get started from this wikipage: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

Comment: Yes I found a lot of guides but none without compilation. For the head of the spec file OK but after I assume that %prep, %build and clean must be empty.

Comment: I try to make a spec file with my binary and my configuration file in BUILD directory and to copy them by a cp cmd in /usr/bin and /usr/etc. Then in the %files part I try to give them the 755 permission. It doesn't work. I'm in a CentOS 6.5. Thanks for your answer anyway, your link is interesting

Answer (score 0):

Create a tar ball with your files on paths (in the tar ball) like ./usr/etc …

Then add the tar ball with a SourceN: directive (choose N appropriately).

In %install do

```
%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}
tar -C %{buildroot} -xvf %{SOURCEn}    # <== choose n same as N in SourceN:
```

Then create %files with the absolute paths (i.e. w/o leading . and/or %buildroot). Use %attr(mode,user,group) if necessary: default %defattr(0644,root,root,0755) is usually what is necessary.

Run "rpm -ba your.spec" to create the binary packages.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't anderstand that it was that simple I totally confused between RPM with sources and without sources.